# sudo: you do not exist in the passwd database

Tags: 20.04, docker

**What do I have**:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt update -y \
    && apt install -y --no-install-recommends \
    sudo \
    && adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" --uid 1000 runner \
    && groupadd docker \
    && usermod -aG sudo runner \
    && usermod -aG docker runner \
    && echo "%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers

USER runner

RUN sudo usermod -u 1001 runner && sudo groupmod -g 121 runner
```

Building this Dockerfile results in an error:

> sudo: you do not exist in the passwd database

If I split the last one `RUN` into two `RUN`s, there is no error:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt update -y \
    && apt install -y --no-install-recommends \
    sudo \
    && adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" --uid 1000 runner \
    && groupadd docker \
    && usermod -aG sudo runner \
    && usermod -aG docker runner \
    && echo "%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers

USER runner

RUN sudo usermod -u 1001 runner
RUN sudo groupmod -g 121 runner
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `RUN sudo usermod -u 1001 runner && sudo groupmod -g 121 runner`, Docker starts an `sh` process as the `runner` user, that runs these commands. The first command changes the UID of that user. But the `sh` process still uses the old ID, and so, when it tries to run the second command, it is trying to run `sudo` with a UID that no longer exists in the `passwd` database. When you split them into two `RUN` commands, Docker starts a new `sh` process for the second `RUN`, which uses the new UID.

I don't have a solution for this, since I don't know why you're doing something like this. I'd advice against randomly changing UIDs of a user while still running processes as that user. `sudo` isn't the only tool that won't like it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to put the `USER` statement after all the `RUN` statements, and remove `sudo` from those commands. That way, the modifications to the user's account all happen as `root`, and so are unaffected by the changes.